# display child div on focus using jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, onfocus

I have the following html markup for my forms:

```
<div class="row has-help">
  <div class="col">Label</div>
  <div class="col"><input /></div>
  <div class="col"><span class="helper">Foobar</span></div>
</div>
```

The above code is repeated several times for different form elements. When the `input` is focussed on i wish to `fadeIn` the `span` in the third col.

I have written the code to accomplish this however when i focus on any `input` on the page all the `span` helpers appear rather than jus the child `span.helper` of `.has-help`.

I have the code on this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cgYQR/2/).

Any help would be greatly appreciated with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select the one inside the closest `div.has-inline-help`

```
$("input").focusin(function() {
           $(".help-inline", $(this).closest('.has-help-inline')).fadeIn(400);
        }).focusout(function () {
            $(".help-inline", $(this).closest('.has-help-inline')).fadeOut(100);
        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/cgYQR/6/

Comment: Thanks for this response, it appears to be the most bullet proof/efficient

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you are selecting all the element with the .help-inline class.
Try to change the javascript to this:

```
$("input").focusin(function() {
   $(this).parent().siblings(".help-inline").fadeIn(400);
}).focusout(function () {
   $(this).parent().siblings(".help-inline").fadeOut(100);
});
```

here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brunoscopelliti/cgYQR/11/), built over your fiddle.

Comment: thanks very much! I can't accept your answer for a few minutes but will do!

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/cgYQR/12/

```
    $("input").focusin(function() {
       $(this).parents(".has-help-inline").find(".help-inline").fadeIn(400);
    })
```

Find the parent of the current input "this" reference. Then find the child to fade in.

Comment: Thanks for this, i like the use of .find from within the parent :-)

Comment: @Matt - it's a more universal/boiler-plate solution, that will work even if you add extra markup. I believe it's slightly more efficient than using ".closest".